# Is there a standard place to make YouTube feature requests?

Tags: youtube

And what is that place?

There's a [help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube), but that seems like it's more for random internet people to help other random internet people, and that is not what I'm looking for.

I could send an e-mail to webmaster@, but that feels intrusive and a bit ridiculous; assuming the e-mail isn't just autofiltered into /var/mail/spam. Plus, from what I remember of RFC 2142, that's probably not how that destination is supposed to be used.

**Details (which you don't need to answer the more general question above):**

I ask specifically because it's been about a decade now, and there still isn't an "autoreplay" checkbox for videos, and that's insane. Not "I will eat your entire family" crazy, but certainly "I will eat one or two members of your family" crazy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

updated for new YouTube layout

In the Youtube <strike>footer</strike> side menu there is a link called "Send feedback". Use that link to send your greetings, complaints, feature requests and anything else directly to the Youtube team.

[image: Youtube side menu]

this was from when it used to be in the footer...
[image: Youtube footer]

Comment: Huh. Usually links like that are in the headers of pages (e.g. About, Press, Policy)... Then again, just realized they're on the bottom for all of Google's pages. I suppose it makes more sense in Google's use case; when you go to one of their sites, you don't care about the company, you only care about the practical, immediate service that company provides, so that service should have precedence visually / navigationally... Neat! (And thank you for drawing my attention to it.)

Comment: Are they even reading it? I mean each and everyone gets taken care of?

Comment: @Shimmy, yes they are.